# Find correlation in bigquery between two columns for each group (in third column)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, correlation

I have a table with columns:

| time | name | metric_a | metric_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1.1 | 1.2 |
| 1 | A | 1. | 1.2. |
| 0 | B | 10 | -1 |
| 1 | B | 12 | 5. |

I want to find the correlation between metric_1 and metric_2 for each distinct name. So in this case the output table would be this shape:

| name | corr |
| --- | --- |
| A | X |
| B | Y |

I know there's a corr function but how to do you get it to calculate correlation for each name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT name, corr(metric_a, metric_b) AS corr from T GROUP BY name
```